# std::getline() does not accept empty input

Tags: c++

I want to be able to accept both a non-empty and empty string (as in just an endline without spaces) as input. The below code works as long as there is no empty input - which will result in the code simply waiting for an input instead of continuing. The cin.ignore() is required for it to not skip the first input (likely because I have other inputs using cin previously). Am I wrong to assume that getline() accepts empty strings?

```
std::cin.ignore(1,'\n');
std::vector<std::string> words(n, "");
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
  std::getline(std::cin, words[i]);
}
```

I have tried using cin.clear() and cin.ignore() within the loop, but it ended up dropping inputs. What should I do to fix this?

Minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  int n = 0;

  std::cin >> n; 
  std::cin.ignore(1,'\n');

  std::vector<std::string> words(n, "");

  for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    std::getline(std::cin, words[i]);

  for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    std::cout << words[i] << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Input

```
5
One
Two
Three

Four
Five
```

Output

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

Expected output

```
One
Two
Three

Four
```

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Sorry, I thought a solution using C was possible.

Comment: @GreenIcedTea Show what an input function is used before the loop and what was entered.

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please! Also you might be interested in reading the [tour] to the end, and inform yourself at our [help] what and how you might asi here.

Comment: Side note on the `std::cin.ignore(1,'\n');`: What if the user's input has more than one character that needs discarding? For example, they accidentally hit space before hitting enter? The canonical solution is to `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` which means ignore everything up to and including the next newline.

Comment: Recommendation: test the stream state after all IO transactions to ensure they were successful. `std::cin >> n;` should be `if (std::cin >> n) { //use n } else { std::cin.clear( ); std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max( ), '\n' ); }`

Comment: the minimum example should include input, output and expected output

Comment: The reason for the `ignore` is that the code is switching from formatted input, which ends at any whitespace, and unformatted input, which has various rules. In the cast of `std::get line` the rule is that the input ends at the next newline character. So if the input that gives the value of `n` ends with a newline you have to get rid of the newline before switching to `getline`.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Still can't reproduce (https://ideone.com/VHHxol) but for different reasons now.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information, but it seems you have *formatted* input on `std::cin` before the loop. Mixing input styles of input on any stream (e.g. formatted input with `std::cin >> ...` and line-oriented input with `std::getline(std::cin, ...`) gives strange interactions because whitespace is handled inconsistently (e.g. one operation will immediately read/discard, another leaves a whitespace waiting to be read).  `ignore()` is an *unreliable* fix. The most *reliable* fix is to use ONLY one inout style (e.g. use `std::getline()` to read *everything* from `std::cin` and parse).

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working now. It seems to have been that the problem was not in my code, but how the terminal was reading inputs. Thank you for taking your time to help me.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, try to avoid mixing formatted and unformatted input operations. `std::cin >> n;` is a formatted operation meanwhile `std::getline(std::cin, words[i]);` is an unformatted operation. This is the part you will have problems with. So you'll have to handle it yourself. I suggest you use only one to have fewer problems.

You might do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>


int main( )
{
    std::string count_str;
    std::getline( std::cin, count_str );
    const std::size_t count { std::stoull( count_str ) };

    std::vector<std::string> words( count, "" );

    for ( std::size_t idx { }; idx != count; ++idx )
    {
        std::getline( std::cin, words[idx] );
    }

    std::cout << "\nwords:\n";

    for ( const auto& word : words )
    {
        std::cout << '\'' << word << "'  ";
    }
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
5
1
2
    // here I skipped the third input
4
5

words:
'1'  '2'  ''  '4'  '5'
```

Your sample:

```
5
One
Two
Three

Four

words:
'One'  'Two'  'Three'  ''  'Four'
```

Comment: @Peter Actually I have mentioned that mixing unformatted and formatted input operations is problematic and also I have recommended removing `std::cin` and only using `std::getline`. And it works properly. I have no idea what those down voters were thinking about.